# Rails 5: handling error messages with rails-ujs and jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-5.1, rails-ujs

In the Rails 5.1.6 I am trying to handle error messages for form with rails-ujs and jquery.

**lot.rb**

```
class Lot < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :user

    mount_uploader :lot_image, LotImageUploader
    serialize :lot_images, JSON # If you use SQLite, add this line.
    default_scope -> { order('created_at DESC') }

    validates_processing_of :lot_image
    validate :image_size_validation
    validates :price, :lot_image, :description, presence: true

  private

    def image_size_validation
      errors[:lot_image] << "should be less than 5MB" if lot_image.size > 5.megabytes
    end
end
```

**lots_controller.rb**

```
...
  def index
    @lot = current_user.lots.build
    @lots = current_user.lots.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end
...
  def create
    @lot = current_user.lots.create(lot_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @lot.save
        format.html { redirect_to @lot, notice: 'Lot was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @lot }
        format.js
      else
        #format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @lot.errors.full_messages, status: :unprocessable_entity }

      end
    end
  end
...
```

As expected, when I submit invalid form I see in browser console  422 status and json response:

```
0."Price can't be blank" 
1."Lot image can't be blank"
2."Description can't be blank"
```

The question is how to render this json response with rails-ujs?

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_with(model: @lot, remote: true, id: :new_lot) do |form| %>
  <div id="errors"></div>

  <%= tag(:input, :type => "hidden", :name => request_forgery_protection_token.to_s, :value => form_authenticity_token) %>

  <%= form.label :description, class: "label label-default" %>
  <%= form.text_area :description, class: "form-control", id: :lot_description, autofocus: true %>

  <%= form.label :price, class: "label label-default" %>
  <%= form.text_field :price, class: "form-control", id: :lot_price %>   

  <%= form.label :lot_image, class: "label label-default" %>
  <%= form.file_field :lot_image, id: :lot_lot_image %>
    <p class="help-block">image must be present, less than 5 Mb.</p>   

  <%= form.submit "create a lot", class: "btn btn-default", data: { "disable-with": "Saving..." } %>
<% end %>
```

**create.js.erb**

```
$('#new_lot').remove();
$('#new_lot_link').show();
$('#lots').prepend('<%= j render(@lot) %>')
```

**application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require rails-ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .


$(document).on("ajax:error", function(event) {
  var detail = event.detail;
  var data = detail[0], status = detail[1],  xhr = detail[2];

  var errors, message, results;
  errors = xhr.responseJSON.error;
  results = [];
  for (message in errors) {
    results.push($('#errors ul').append('<li>' + errors[message] + '</li>'));
  }
  return results;
});
```

What is going on wrong? Thanks for any explanation and especially for the solution (;

Answer (score 3):

Like a last man on the Earth, I am talking to myself (8

I solved this problem. Maybe someone will be interested too.

```
$(document).on("ajax:error", function(event) {
  var detail = event.detail;
  var data = detail[0], status = detail[1],  xhr = detail[2];
  var errors = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
  var er ="<ul>";
    for(var i = 0; i < errors.length; i++){
        var list = errors[i];
        er += "<li>"+list+"</li>"
   }
    er+="</ul>"
    $("#errors").html(er);
});
```

Comment: It only calls if the ajax request fails, nothing to do with the Rails functionality on the server

Answer (score 0):

How about this way? It is not clean because have some controller's work in js file but it works for me. I also can not find other easy way.

**create.js.erb**

```
<% if !@lot.errors.any? %>
  $('#new_lot').remove();
  $('#new_lot_link').show();
  $('#lots').prepend('<%= j render(@lot) %>')
  <% @lot = Lot.new %>
<% end %>
$("#new_lot_form").html("<%= j (render 'form', lot: @lot) %>")
```

Make sure you show errors in **_form.html.erb** partial.

```
<% if lot.errors.any? %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: form.object %>
<% end %>
```

When you reload form with @lot variable from create action it shows error massages. If no errors it will append new record and need to make new @lot variable <% @lot = Lot.new %> because otherwise form will get already saved object and next time will send you to update action.

Add format.js to else part of if @lot.save in **lots_controller.erb**

```
...
respond_to do |format|
  if @lot.save
    format.html { redirect_to lots_path, notice: 'Lot was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @lot }
    format.js
  else
    format.html { render :index }
    format.json { render json: @lot.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    format.js
  end
end
...
```

Wrap form on **index.erb** with div#new_lot

```
<div id="new_lot_form">
  <%= render 'form', lot: @lot %>
</div>
```